# How to use sys/mount to mount a NFS system?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, mount, nfs

So, I am trying to connect two Ubuntu computers using a NFS connection
On the server, I made the following

1. Install NFS Server on Ubuntu

   $ sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server portmap
2. Export shares over NFS

   $ sudo mkdir /opt/share
   $ sudo chown nobody:nogroup /opt/share
3. Edit the NFS server exports configuration file

   $ sudo gedit /etc/exports
4. Add the following settings

   /home          192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
   /opt/share     192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
5. Apply the new settings by running the following command. This will export all directories listed in /etc/exports file

   $ sudo exportfs -a

On the client side, I tried to use the sys/mount   library to make the NFS connection

```
if(mount(":/mnt/share","/opt/share","nfs",0,"nolock,addr=192.168.0.101") == -1)
  {
    printf("NFS ERROR: mount failed: %s \n",strerror(errno));
  }
  else
  { 
    printf("NFS connected\n");
  }
```

But it returns

```
m@m-ThinkPad-L15-Gen-2:~/Desktop/teste$ sudo ./mountnfs
NFS ERROR: mount failed: Permission denied
```

Does anybody have any clue of what is happening?

Comment: The syntax for `mount()` is `mount(source, target, ...)` - you've exported `/opt/share`, why is your source `/mnt/share`? Also which NFS versions is the server exporting, and which NFS versions is your client attempting? (you can specify the version in the mount options)? Also `/opt/share` doesn't have `no_root_squash`, what are the permissions server's root inode (`/opt/share`)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mount):

> Linux: the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability is required to mount file systems.

And according to [this page](https://www.vultr.com/docs/working-with-linux-capabilities/), you can add that capability to your program using something along the lines of the following command (each time after you build it, probably):

`sudo setcap CAP_SYS_ADMIN+ep /path/to/your/binary`

That's the gist of it anyway, but you might need to a bit more digging to find the optimal solution - in which case you can answer your own question.

Also, what's that leading `:` doing in your `source` parameter?  Most likely I just don't understand the syntax, but it looks a bit weird to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After I use the setcap command on my file, it still returns permission denied..
About the ":" it is necessary, otherwise it returns "NFS ERROR: mount failed: Invalid argument "

Comment: OK, well, it's a start.  Have you tried it running your program as root, and have you tried it from the command line?  Maybe [this thread](https://www.vultr.com/docs/working-with-linux-capabilities/) can help.

Comment: Yes, I always run it as sudo. But I found the error, the source and destination folders were inverted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, good.  Maybe with `setcap` you won't need to (which would be a big plus, IMO).